# Task.Delay or Thread.Sleep to pause execution in a sync method

Tags: c#, async-await, thread-safety, task

I want to pause a sync method. I know I can to use:

```
// SAMPLE 01
Thread.Sleep(30 * 1000)
```

but it has a disadvantage of blocking the current thread. The alternative

```
// SAMPLE 02
await Task.Delay(30 * 1000)
```

will work only in an async method. But I need this in a **sync** method. We cannot do it like this

```
// SAMPLE 03
Task.Delay(30 * 1000).Wait()
```

because it can cause a deadlock (at least I think so). My final solution is

```
// SAMPLE 04
Task.Run(() => Task.Delay(30 * 1000)).Wait();
```

Finally, my question: Is this solution (**SAMPLE 04**) really better than the **SAMPLE 01** (using Thread.Sleep)?

Bonus question: **SAMPLE 03** really can do a deadlock? What if we do this:

```
// SAMPLE 05
Task.Delay(30 * 1000).Wait(30 * 1000)
```

Comment: Thread.Sleep is the way to go. Synchronously blocking on an async call is wasteful, you are basically running the delay task on a background thread where you then block on it to finish. Just use Thread.Sleep

Comment: Why blocking the current thread is a disadvantage? Isn't it the sole intention of this exercise?

Comment: If you want to tie up the *thread-pool* Thread, use `Thread.Sleep`, if you want to return the *Thread back to the *thread-pool use `await Task.Delay`. End of story. Using `Task.Delay(30 * 1000).Wait(30 * 1000)` or other variants will do nothing but make you fail a code review

Comment: @TheodorZoulias blocking the current thread is in fact the whole point but there are right and wrong ways to achieve this. All the samples apart from 1 is the wrong way of doing it. These samples, instead of simply suspending the current thread, it fakes it by blocking on a task running on a background thread. We are wasting a background thread to achieve functionality that is already there to use, i.e. Sample 1.

Comment: Your post is essentially "I want to block current thread but when I do it the thread is blocked"... Not exactly clear what you want to achieve and especially *what you want to avoid*. The code-golf like exercise on how to make thread to pause for some time in most interesting ways does not make the problem any more clear.

Comment: very hard to tell what you want to achieve, possibly you don't want to block a UI thread?  not sure.  If that's the case, put the whole synchronous process in a separate thread, and then synchronize it with the UI thread.  Alternatively, you really do want async (or you will be reinventing it yourself) or another approach might be to create a timer with a timeout event where the rest of your synch process will carry on from.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is this solution (SAMPLE 04) really better than the SAMPLE 01 (using Thread.Sleep)?

No. It's worse. Sample 01 is both more understandable and more efficient.

> it has a disadvantage of blocking the current thread.

It is true that `Thread.Sleep` blocks the current thread. In an asynchronous method, that would be a disadvantage.

> I need this in a sync method.

By definition, then, you *want* to block the current thread. That's what synchronous means.

And in fact, all your examples *do* block the calling thread (except 02, which is asynchronous). `Wait` blocks the calling thread just as much as `Thread.Sleep` does.

> SAMPLE 03 really can do a deadlock?

No. In order to have a deadlock, you need two different things waiting for each other before they can continue. For the [classical sync-over-async deadlock](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html), your two things are:

1. An `async` method whose `await` has captured a single-threaded context.
2. A thread blocked in that same context.

In your example, you have a thread blocked. Let's assume there's a single-threaded context and the thread is blocked in that context. You still wouldn't have a deadlock because the `Task.Delay` method does not capture its context. So there won't be a deadlock.