# Using Task.Delay in synchronous method results in high memory consumption

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task, scheduled-tasks

I know that what am about to show is wrong, but I want to know what exactly is going on. I can not attach images because of my low reputation.

I have .NET 7 API project.

I use `Task.Delay()` in sync method (API):

```
using (var client = new HttpClient() { Timeout = System.TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15)})
{
    var response = client.GetAsync("https://...");

    var canProceed = false;    

    while (!canProceed)
    {
        if (response.IsCompleted)
        {
            canProceed = true;
        }
        Task.Delay(25);
    }; 
}
```

I know that `Task.Delay()` does not delay.

Then I use a separate console app and hit this API using `Parallel.For` - 10.000 times. Using JetBrains dotMemory, I got terrible results in memory consumption. After just a few seconds running the console app that hits the Api, the memory of the API app grows from 100mb to 4GB. When I compare the two snapshots - the "SurvivedBytes" shows that **ConcurrentQueue<Object>** owns 80 bytes but retains 3GB. The "Memory Allocations" section of the tool shows that 2GB is allocated to **TimerQueueTimer**, and 1GB to **Task + DelayPromise**.

Interestingly enough, garbage collector does not collect the memory (I got warning of a high GC pressure), unless I use "Force GC" several times.

When I replace the `Task.Delay(25)` with `Thread.Sleep(25)` the API app is working fine under high load - the GC working intensively, but still keeping the memory under 150mb.

I know that I can not just use `Task.Delay()` like this in sync method, I just want to know what is going here.

I did read this (and other related topics):
[Task.Delay or Thread.Sleep to pause execution in a sync method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56229244/task-delay-or-thread-sleep-to-pause-execution-in-a-sync-method)

**--UPDATE--**
Thank you all for the help. I know that this code is nonsense, it does not delay. I am using sync method, so I can not use await. I can use Thread.Sleep(25) which actually does what is supposed to do. I was interested in why the GC can not free the memory allocated to this:

[image]

[image]

[image]

And when I use "Force GC" in JetBrains several times, it actually does release the memory, but id does not release it on it's on.

Comment: I guess `Task.Delay(25)` creates a task, which holding context of calling method. That's why GC can't free it. Could you try `Task.Delay(25).ConfigureAwait(false)`?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you can't use `await` here? Or why can't you use `Thread.Sleep`? Also this code is creating `Task` (from `Task.Delay`) at crazy speed because nothing is stopping the `while` loop from keep running and running.

Comment: At worst, would `Task.Delay(25).Wait()` work for you?

Comment: @LukeVo: If you're going to call `Wait()` on a task instance, why not call it on the I/O task (`response.Wait()`) ?

Comment: @BenVoigt agree, and while we are at it, if `await` is not available at all, better just use `Send` instead of `SendAsync` or `GetAsync`.

Comment: ​The line `Task.Delay(25);` is pretty much equivalent with creating a `System.Threading.Timer`, and scheduling an action to run after 25 milliseconds. You are doing it in a tight loop, which results to a ton of scheduling. The .NET timer-related infrastructure is highly optimized, but it still might not be able to cope efficiently with this level of abuse. Your question is basically "I hit my donkey with a baseball bat with all my force for an hour for absolutely no reason and she died. Please explain why she died."

Comment: "Using JetBrains dotMemory, I got terrible results in memory consumption." - Yes, you're allocating resources (`Task.Delay(25)` creates a task, after all) in a tight loop. It's not clear why you'd expect anything *other* than a bad result here.#

Answer (score 2):

`Task.Delay(25);` is not awaited and will not block the cycle, it will just spin up all the underlying infrastructure and that's it, so basically you will constantly invoke `Task.Delay(25);` until the response will complete without any waiting/blocking. Hence the resources consuption.

You of course can block on it with `Task.Delay(25).GetAwaiter().GetResult();` but you really [should not block on async code](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html). Use `Thread.Sleep`. Or `response.GetAwaiter().GetResult()`.

Or much-much better - make your method async and await the client call (API methods can be async and arguably should in most cases):

```
var response = await client.GetAsync("https://...");
```

Also consider using [`IHttpClientFactory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests) instead of creating `HttpClient` manually.